# Can Python use a functions default parameter when an inline if fails when calling it?

Tags: python-3.x

If I have a variable that has a value I don't want passed to a function, is it possible to do it without several ifs, especially if there are several variables that may or may not need to be passed in?
Take the following:

```
def test(param=""):
    ...do stuff

x = None

test(x if x else ?)
                 ^
     What can i put here so it
     defaults to the default in 
     the function definition?
```

If this isn't possible, is there a quick way of doing this when there are multiple variables that may or may not need to be passed in rather than a lot of ifs?

Answer (score 0):

Basic answer:

```
if(x): test(x)
else: test()
```

With *args you can pass in as many variables as you want but I don't think that will help you. The best I can think of is multiple ifs (Python doesn't allow overloading unfortunately).

That would look like:

```
if x:
    if y:
        if z: test(x,y,z)
        else: test(x,y)
    else: test(x)
else: test()
```

The reason you can't call test(x,z) or test(y) for example is because your method assumes a certain order in the signature so you wouldn't be able to specify which arg you are passing in at function call. In Java you could do it with overloading and different argument types, but not here afaik.